# What is wrong with this contains(T entry) method? Java. Linked List

Tags: java, list, generics, linked-list, sentinel

I'm making a linked list class and am trying to implement this `contains()` method.

I have `head` and `tail` sentinel nodes, so I have the loop start at `head.next`. `length` is the size of the list. Bout all I can give you guys :O

```
public boolean contains(T entry) {

    boolean found = false;
    Node current = head.next;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        if (current.equals(entry)) {

            found = true;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? Does it not work? Does it break? Besides, this doesn't even compile without more context. What is "length", for example?

Comment: sorry for not being specific. in my tester, i am just using strings, if I add "hello" to my list for example and call myList.contains("hello"); it returns false. i have thoroughly tested my add method, it definitely works. length is how many items are in my list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're comparing a `Node` to a `T` which if your equals method correctly fufills the correct contract will always return false being different classes.

i.e. re-examine this line:

```
if (current.equals(entry)) {
```